# Returning a default UICollectionViewCell is missing a reuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift

If i try to return the default `UICollectionViewCell` the app crashes because it is missing a `reuseIdentifier:`

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the cell returned from
>   -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling
>   -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'

The code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

With `UITableViewCells` it's working just fine. What is the best practice for default returns in `UICollectionViews`?

Comment: There is no such thing as `dequeueReusableCell(withType: for:)`. What ever extension you used for your table view cell, you need to use similar for your collection view cell.

Comment: That's custom and not needed in this context. Its just about the return of UICollectionViewCell(). let cell.. wont get called. Its just a snipped to show the problem

Comment: Why would `model` be `nil`?  Your `numberOfItems` should return 0 if `model` is `nil`. You should probably just call `fatalError` in that `guard` or force unwrap `model`

Comment: Its just a very tiny snipped from the actual code. Its just about the question why i cant return the normal default UICollectionViewCell() like it is the normal practice in UITableViews

Comment: Ok, a simpler answer for your edited code - you just can't do that. As the exception says, you must dequeue a cell. You can simply dequeue an appropriate cell type.

Comment: @Paulw11 Are you sure? It's totally normal in UITableViews

Comment: If that method doesn't get called, it means `numberOfItems` return 0 item.

Comment: @Desdenova The method gets called. I just wonder why i can't return UIColletionViewCell() as default like its normally done in TableViews

Comment: Even if it is supported in tableviews, I wouldn't do it. It suggests that something is wrong in your logic if you are being asked for cells where there is no data. But the exception message is pretty clear.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's like 0,0001% of the actual project with multiple sections, rows / tableViews in collections and so on. It's normal to guard optional code and return a default value. I just want to know what that default value would be. Even if it will never get called. I just want to return  something. The error i show above never really happend in my project. It's just something that i wanted to check. But you just says its bad code without understanding the real question

Comment: Yes, it's bad code because you should always have a specific cell to return, however you can just register `UICollectionViewCell` for a reuse identifier such as `Default` and then dequeue an instance of `Default`

Comment: @JonasSchafft But you never told us about your real problem. Anyways, he told you a solution with his first comment. Just throw fatal error.

Comment: @Paulw11 I always have a cell to return and i`m 100% sure the code will never get executed. But even with that confidence i want to return a valid value in my guard and i just wanted to know what that value would be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What works for me is:

```
collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "default")
```

and then:

```
return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "default", for: indexPath)
```

as the default return. But i was hoping for something cleaner.